# How can I run a lineman project in Jenkins so the protractor tests can find the browser?

Tags: maven, jenkins, protractor, linemanjs

I have a project which is setup with lineman and uses maven for build configurations. A maven pom.xml file is used to configure the jenkins builds. This file lists the necessary tasks that need to be done in order to build the project. The lineman tasks are specified here as well. The command `lineman grunt spec-e2e` starts the protractor tests.

This currently works on the jenkins server because it starts the webdriver and runs the tests. However, all specs in the tests fail since `browser.get('myurl')` can't find anything since nothing is running. I tried to add `lineman run` as a task but this causes the jenkins-build to get stuck on the watch task.

How can I get the project to run and therefore make it accessible for the protractor tests?